# Generate list of people with all their MyTreeTags™ from an Ancestry online tree?

Tags: ancestry.com

For a single Ancestry online tree, I would like to generate a list of all people plus all the MyTreeTags™ associated with each person. For instance:

Tree Name

- Person One: Tag1, Tag2
- Person Two: Tag1, Tag3
- Person Three:
- Person Four: Tag1, Tag2, Tag3

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, what you'd like to see is a list similar to the List of All People in your tree followed by the MyTreeTags™ you've assigned to that person.

Looking at the support article [MyTreeTags™](https://support.ancestry.com/s/article/MyTreeTags) and other help materials about MyTreeTags, Ancestry hasn't given us any quick and easy way to do that.  If you want such a list, you'll have to make one yourself using a tool like a spreadsheet.

Scraping the List of all People from Ancestry's online tree system can be tedious, so you might consider using a tool like GEDmagic's [GEDxlate](http://www.gedmagic.com/GEDxlate.htm) to convert your GEDcom into an Excel file instead of doing it by hand.  GEDxlate gives you the choice of several outputs, including a text file.

Before you embark on your project, think about what it is you're trying to determine and whether your choice of how you display the list will make a difference to you.  Do you want just a raw list, or would it be more helpful to create a spreadsheet/table and make filled-in cells for all the people who have a certain tag assigned?

Is a list going to suit your needs? Or would you be better served by a full-featured program such as [GenDetective](https://www.rumblesoftinc.com/) or [GenSmarts](http://gensmarts.com/), or a GEDcom analysis tool like [Family Tree Analyzer](http://ftanalyzer.com/)?

If all you need is a simple list to keep you on track about which profiles you've tagged or not tagged yet, a spreadsheet might be easier to update and keep tidy than a list in a document.  One rule of thumb: the best tool is the one you will actually use.

Resource list:

- YouTube video: [Use MyTreeTags™, New on Ancestry | The Barefoot Genealogist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Idv1_zR8qs) by Ancestry's Crista Cowan
- YouTube video: [What Do All the Ancestry.com MyTreeTags Mean?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB8KaVMzUzw) by
  Family History Fanatics's Devon Noel Lee
- YouTube video: [A Review of Ancestry.com MyTreeTags - Genealogy Research Tips and Tricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFrH70VHjhw) by Family History Fanatics' Devon Noel Lee
- Blog: [Ancestry’s MyTreeTags](https://thednageek.com/ancestrys-mytreetags/) at The DNA Geek